# Every record of subform table being updated on update trigger

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, triggers, subform

I have a form in Access with linked tables in SQL Server called Outage Summary. There are a few subforms, but only one called Outage Details is of concern. The form and subform are linked by a property called `OutageSummaryID`. There can be multiple Outage Details for each Outage Summary, and each Outage Detail record has a unique `OutageDetailID`.

I have a trigger for each table in SQL Server that records each `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` that is performed and adds them to an audit table along with the dateTime of when and what user performed the action.

Anytime you edit and update any Outage Summary or add and Outage Detail, the Outage Details Audit table is populated with a record for each `OutageDetailID` that says the record was updated at the same time. I don't believe that Access would actually be updating every record in the table. Maybe there is a problem with my trigger (though every other trigger is written the same way and functions as intended) or there is something fundamentally flawed with what I am doing.  How can I fix this?

My trigger:

```
USE [OutageDev]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_audOutageDetails]
ON  [dbo].[Outage Details SubTbl]
AFTER INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE

AS 

BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for trigger here
IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Inserted) AND EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Deleted)

    INSERT INTO dbo.[Outage Details Audit] (OutageSummaryID, [TimeOut], /* ... */ OutageDetailID, AuditDateTime, AuditUser, AuditAction)
        SELECT i.OutageSummaryID, i.[TimeOut], /* ... */ i.OutageDetailID, GETDATE(), SUSER_SNAME(), 'UPDATE'
        FROM inserted i join deleted d on i.OutageDetailID = d.OutageDetailID

IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Inserted) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Deleted)

    INSERT INTO dbo.[Outage Details Audit] (OutageSummaryID, [TimeOut], /* ... */ OutageDetailID, AuditDateTime, AuditUser, AuditAction)
        SELECT OutageSummaryID, [TimeOut], /* ... */ OutageDetailID, GETDATE(), SUSER_SNAME(), 'INSERT'
        FROM inserted 

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Inserted) AND EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Deleted)

    INSERT INTO dbo.[Outage Details Audit] (OutageSummaryID, [TimeOut], /* ... */ OutageDetailID, AuditDateTime, AuditUser, AuditAction)
        SELECT OutageSummaryID, [TimeOut], /* ... */ OutageDetailID, GETDATE(), SUSER_SNAME(), 'DELETE'
        FROM deleted 

END
```

I had the same issue before adding the join on the UPDATE trigger, I just added it to... I guess further convince myself that rows are actually being deleted and inserted. It functions the same with or without the join.

Comment: Could you post the `UPDATE` statement that triggers the problem?

Comment: There isn't an UPDATE statement. They are linked tables so it would be Access' Update function.

Comment: Perhaps using [SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091(v=sql.100).aspx) will provide a better idea of what Access is asking SQL Server to do.